# how to use Warp filter of jhlabs image library in android

Tags: android, image, filter, warp, morphing

I want to use `WarpFilter` of `jhlabs` in my android application.For that i used jar provided by jhlabs but in that , there is no definition of WarpFilter class. I reffered [WarpFilter](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/WarpFilter.html) and [this](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/) link.I tried to use that class by copying it in my application. But the problem is that, it uses some classes which are not supported by android sdk. I also reffered [Google code](https://code.google.com/p/android-jhlabs/source/browse/trunk/src/com/jabistudio/androidjhlabs/distortionandwarpingactivity/WarpFilterActivity.java) link, but it also doesn't provide any implementation for that.Please anyone can suggest me some solution ? is there any other librabry/jar which provide warping image facility ? Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: no...i haven't found any solution

Comment: any ideas at this moment? i have same situation at this time..

Comment: @MayurR.Amipara  no idea.

Comment: than any other good way or library to do this? i am working on current app which will be work same like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.piviandco.fatbooth&hl=en)... any suggestion for do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a filter like this:

```
final Bitmap bmporg = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArrayorg, 0, byteArrayorg.length);

Line line1 = new Line(0, 0, bmporg.getWidth(), 0);
Line line2 = new Line(0, bmporg.getHeight()/2, bmporg.getWidth(), bmporg.getHeight()/2);
Line line3 = new Line(0, bmporg.getHeight(), bmporg.getWidth(), bmporg.getHeight());

final Line[] lineArray = {line1, line2, line3 };

Line line4 = new Line(0, 0, bmporg.getWidth(), bmporg.getHeight());
Line line5 = new Line(0, 0, bmporg.getWidth(), bmporg.getHeight());
Line line6 = new Line(0, 0, bmporg.getWidth(), bmporg.getHeight());

final Line[] lineArray2 = {line4, line5, line6 };

FieldWarpFilter fieldWarpFilter = new FieldWarpFilter();
fieldWarpFilter.setAmount(amountFieldWarpFilter);
fieldWarpFilter.setPower(powerFieldWarpFilter);
fieldWarpFilter.setStrength(strengthFieldWarpFilter);
fieldWarpFilter.setInLines(lineArray);
fieldWarpFilter.setOutLines(lineArray2);
int[] src22 = AndroidUtils.bitmapToIntArray(bmporg);
int width22 = bmporg.getWidth();
int height22 = bmporg.getHeight();
int[] dest22 = fieldWarpFilter.filter(src22, width22, height22);
Bitmap destBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dest22, width22, height22, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

imageView1.setImageBitmap(destBitmap);
```